# In JOOQ, if I directly use the underlying connection, is my transactional status maintained?

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, kotlin, jooq

Lets assume I have a JOOQ `DSLContext` object, and I need to drop down to the level of the JDBC `Connection` object to perform some non-JOOQ logic. (In my case, I want to use the Postgres driver's `CopyManager` object).

If my `DSLContext` is transactional, will the operations performed directly on the `Connection` be wrapped by the same transaction? I am using JOOQ's default transaction provider.

e.g. (Kotlin code, but should be pretty transparent to Java users)

```
dsl.transaction { transactionConfig ->
    val transactionalDSL = DSL.using(transactionConfig)
    transactionalDSL.connection { connection ->
        val manager = CopyManager(connection as BaseConnection)
        manager.copyInto(table, inputStream, fields)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your API usage is correct.

#### Optimal API usage

The important thing when using [`DSLContext.transaction(TransactionalRunnable)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#transaction-org.jooq.TransactionalRunnable-) is to use the argument configuration, which you called `transactionConfig` for all database interactions within the transaction boundary (not the outer `dsl` reference, which remains unmodified and might return a new connection from the connection pool).

In other words, the `transactionConfig` is a `Configuration` that guarantees to always return the very same JDBC `Connection` from the transaction's scope, regardless of your `DataSource` / `ConnectionProvider` configuration.

#### Working with thread-bound transactions

The above is a guarantee by jOOQ, but of course you can assure thread-bound transactions also on a lower level, e.g.:

- By using the jOOQ `ThreadLocalTransactionProvider` along with [`DSLContext.transaction(ContextTransactionRunnable)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#transaction-org.jooq.ContextTransactionalRunnable-), in case of which your logic would look like this:

  ```kotlin
  dsl.transaction { () ->
      dsl.connection { connection ->
          val manager = CopyManager(connection as BaseConnection)
          manager.copyInto(table, inputStream, fields)
      }
  }
  ```
- By using a thread-bound, transactional connection pool or DataSource. In this case, your `dsl.configuration().connectionProvider()` should return the same connection as `transactionConfig.connectionProvider()`, and this would be transparent to jOOQ.

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally, the answer seems to be yes.